InvalidArgumentException Disk [minio] does not have a configured driver error
When I try to connect to minio error like this
when i try to connect minio server there is error like this

InvalidArgumentException Disk [minio] does not have a configured driver.

I am appy directory key  and secret key filesystem.php how to solve this issue?

Your question lacks minimal reproducible example. Have you added minio to filesystems.php config file?
